# Is it possible to match several value in case when statment for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Consider example:

```
case when type = 'myValue' then 'default' else type end
```

how to listed several values here `type = 'myValue'`? Instead of duplicating:

```
case
     when type = 'myValue' then 'default'
     when type = 'other' then 'default'
     else type
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use any condition in a `when` clause. E.g., in your case, you could use the `in` operator:

```
case
     when type in ('myValue','other') then 'default'
     else type
end
```